# OpenLayers 6: Converting extent coords to lon/lat

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a bbox extent in the form

```
[-2460660.814556394,-2935181.886150768,2460660.814556394,2935181.886150768].
```

I want to convert it into lon/lat coords, probably using `proj.toLonLat()`, but am not sure how I can do it on an entire extent. Hoping I don't have to split it up, transform it, and then reconnect it again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ol.proj.transformExtent` method to directly transform extent (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.transformExtent). When using this method you have to specify both source and destination CRS.

Since you want to convert projected coordinates (probably Web Mercator) to unprojected coordinates, in your case that could look something like this:

```
var mercatorExtent = [-2460660.814556394,-2935181.886150768, 2460660.814556394 ,2935181.886150768];
var lonLatExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(mercatorExtent, 'EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326');
```